# Why doesn't my form display in a modal dialog box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a webpage (MVC) where I'm using jQuery to open a contact form in a modal dialog box.  I was following the instructions at this location, http://amitraya.blogspot.com/2012/09/modal-dialog-form-view-using-jquery.html?showComment=1456279968693#c1669084113853730370.  Instead of showing up in a modal dialog, the form shows on a separate webpage by itself.  I've commented some things out, changed some versions and got many results other than the one I want.  I think something may be clashing.  Can someone tell me why my form won't show up in a modal dialog box like I want?  Thanks for any help.  The pertinent code is as follows:

_Layout.cshtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="Clarence Benoit">
        <title>Background Sound - The Sound System Rental Company</title>
        <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
        <link href="Content/themes/base/minified/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <!-- Custom CSS -->
        <link href="Content/backgroundsound.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    @*@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")*@
    @*@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")*@
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
```

```
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Background Sound</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#packages">Packages</a></li>
                <li><a href="#gallery">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#credit">Credit</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>
<!-- Full Width Image Header -->
<header class="header-image">
    <div class="headline">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Background Sound</h1>
            <h2>Will Rock Your World</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<!-- Page Content -->
<div class="container">
    @RenderBody()
    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <p>Copyright &copy; 2016 Background Sound.&nbsp;&nbsp;All Rights Reserved.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
</div>
<!-- /.container -->
@*@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")*@
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".openDialog").live("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("<div></div>").addClass("dialog").att("id", $(this).attr("data-dialog-id")).appendTo("body").dialog({ title: $(this).attr("data-dialog-title"), close: function () { $(this).remove() }, modal: true }).load(this.href);
        });

        $(".close").live("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var senderName = $("#senderName").val();
            var senderEmail = $("#senderEmail").val();
            var message = $("#message").text();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Home/SendEmail",
                data: { "senderName": senderName, "senderEmail": senderEmail, "message": message },
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("Your email was successfully sent.");
                    $(this).closest(".dialog").dialog("close");
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert("There was an error sending your email.  Please try again or contact system administrator.");
                    $(this).closest(".dialog").dialog("close");
                }
            })
        });
    });
</script>
```

Index.cshtml:
(the ActionLink is what's supposed to open the modal dialog)

```
<div class="featurette" id="contact">
    <img class="featurette-image img-circle img-responsive pull-left" src="Images/contactus.gif" height="500" width="500">
    <h2 class="featurette-heading">
            Contact Us
            <span class="text-muted"></span>
        </h2>
        <p class="lead text-center">
            <br /><br />You can contact us by calling 816.529.9986 or<br />clicking @Html.ActionLink("here", "SendEmail", "Home", null, new {@class="openDialog", data_dialog_id="sendEmail", data_dialog_title="Contact Us"}) to send an email.
        </p>
    </div>
    <hr class="featurette-divider">
```

(the below div is at the bottom of the view and where the partial view is loaded)

```
<div id="emailForm"></div>
```

SendEmail.cshtml (partial view):

```
@model BackgroundSoundBiz.Models.EmailModel

<form id="sendEmailForm">
    <div id="sendForm">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.senderName)<br />
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.senderName)
        <br />
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.senderEmail)<br />
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.senderEmail)
        <br />
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.message)<br />
        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.message)
        <br />
        <input class="close" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
</form>
```

EmailModel.cs:

```
public class EmailModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Name")]
        public string senderName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string senderEmail { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Message")]
        public string message { get; set; }
    }
```

SendEmail method in HomeController.cs:

```
public ActionResult SendEmail()
        {
            return PartialView("SendEmail", new EmailModel());
        }
```

Rendered page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="Clarence Benoit">
        <title>Background Sound - The Sound System Rental Company</title>
        <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
        <link href="Content/themes/base/minified/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <!-- Custom CSS -->
        <link href="Content/backgroundsound.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->




        <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>

    </head>
<body>

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Background Sound</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#packages">Packages</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#gallery">Gallery</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#credit">Credit</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>
    <!-- Full Width Image Header -->
    <header class="header-image">
        <div class="headline">
            <div class="container">
                <h1>Background Sound</h1>
                <h2>Will Rock Your World</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container">


<hr class="featurette-divider">
<!-- First Featurette -->
<div class="featurette" id="about">
    <img class="featurette-image img-circle img-responsive pull-right" src="Images/aboutus.jpg" height="500" width="500">
    <h2 class="featurette-heading">
        About Us
        <span class="text-muted"></span>
    </h2>
    <p class="lead">
        Background Sound is a new innovative and inexpensive way to get the professional sound system you need for you events and parties at a fraction of the cost.&nbsp;&nbsp;Here's how it works!&nbsp;&nbsp;
        You provide you own music by laptop, iPod, or tablet and we do the rest.&nbsp;&nbsp;We'll provide you with a high quality professional sound system, which can consist of brands such as JBL, QSC,
        Electro-Voice (EV), Crown, Mackie, and Sure.&nbsp;&nbsp;Lighting and wedding uplighting is also available.&nbsp;&nbsp;We deliver, setup, and take down all equipment.&nbsp;&nbsp;We do have DJs available
        if you desire.&nbsp;&nbsp;A sound technician remains at your event operating the sound system and lighting portion of you event assuring you the highest sound quality available making sure your event
        is a night to remember while you DJ your party your way with your own style of music.
    </p>
</div>
<hr class="featurette-divider">

<!-- Third Featurette -->
<div class="featurette" id="packages">
    <img class="featurette-image img-circle img-responsive pull-left" src="http://placehold.it/500x500">
    <h2 class="featurette-heading">
        Packages
        <span class="text-muted"></span>
    </h2>
    <p class="lead text-center">
        <span style="display:block;">Wedding - $350.00</span><br />
        2 - 15" two-way speakers • 2 speaker tripod stands • 2 speaker stand decorative white skrims • 1 table (4 ft) with decorative white or black skrim cover • 1 corded mic with 25 ft cable
    </p>
    <p class="lead">
        <span class="text-center" style="display:block;">Upgrades</span><br />
        <span class="pull-left">Wireless Mic</span><span class="pull-right">$40.00</span><br />
        <span class="pull-left">Party Lights</span><span class="pull-right">$75.00</span><br />
        <span class="pull-left">Subs</span><span class="pull-right">$100.00</span><br />
        <span class="pull-left">Dinner Lighting (Uplights)</span><span class="pull-right">$20.00/light</span><br />
        <span class="pull-left">Cake Pin Spot</span><span class="pull-right">$60.00</span><br /><br />
    </p>
    <p class="lead">The cake pin spot is used to help show the beauty of your cake or personalize a table for the bride and groom only.</p>
</div>
<hr class="featurette-divider">

<!-- Fourth Featurette -->
<div class="featurette" id="gallery">
    <img class="featurette-image img-circle img-responsive pull-right" src="http://placehold.it/500x500">
    <h2 class="featurette-heading">
        Gallery
        <span class="text-muted"></span>
    </h2>
    <p class="lead">
        Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.
    </p>
</div>
<hr class="featurette-divider">

<!-- Fifth Featurette -->
<div class="featurette" id="contact">
    <img class="featurette-image img-circle img-responsive pull-left" src="Images/contactus.gif" height="500" width="500">
    <h2 class="featurette-heading">
        Contact Us
        <span class="text-muted"></span>
    </h2>
    <p class="lead text-center">
        <br /><br />You can contact us by calling 816.529.9986 or<br />clicking <a class="openDialog" data-dialog-id="sendEmail" data-dialog-title="Contact Us" href="/Home/SendEmail">here</a> to send an email.
    </p>
</div>
<hr class="featurette-divider">

<!-- Sixth Featurette -->
<div class="featurette" id="credit">
    <img class="featurette-image img-circle img-responsive pull-right" src="Images/acknowledgements.gif" height="500" width="500">
    <h2 class="featurette-heading">
        Credits
        <span class="text-muted"></span>
    </h2>
    <p class="lead text-center">
        <br /><br />Website constructed by Clarence Benoit<br /><br />Need a website<br />personal or small business<br />call 816.898.6870.
    </p>
</div>
<hr class="featurette-divider">

<div id="emailForm"></div>
        <!-- Footer -->
        <footer>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                    <p>Copyright &copy; 2016 Background Sound.&nbsp;&nbsp;All Rights Reserved.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->



    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".openDialog").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $("<div></div>").addClass("dialog").att("id", $(this).attr("data-dialog-id")).appendTo("body").dialog({ title: $(this).attr("data-dialog-title"), close: function () { $(this).remove() }, modal: true }).load(this.href);
            });

            $(".close").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var senderName = $("#senderName").val();
                var senderEmail = $("#senderEmail").val();
                var message = $("#message").text();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Home/SendEmail",
                    data: { "senderName": senderName, "senderEmail": senderEmail, "message": message },
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert("Your email was successfully sent.");
                        $(this).closest(".dialog").dialog("close");
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        alert("There was an error sending your email.  Please try again or contact system administrator.");
                        $(this).closest(".dialog").dialog("close");
                    }
                })
            });
        });
    </script>

<!-- Visual Studio Browser Link -->
<script type="application/json" id="__browserLink_initializationData">
    {"appName":"Firefox","requestId":"ac6dd739aa2b4e58a67eda5ec66a09bc"}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:49245/f88ffa026ad94b73bfa9b9bbddf32f30/browserLink" async="async"></script>
<!-- End Browser Link -->

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You need to find a better tutorial! There are multiple issues (many of which no doubt are showing errors in the browser console). It difficult to tell exactly which scripts your loading and which order because of your 'comment' indicators and what is `"~/Scripts/jquery.js"` (which version) and `.live` has been depreciated. The reason its displaying a new page is your `$(".openDialog").live("click", function (e) {` is not executing so you doing a normal redirect.

Comment: Thanks Stephen.  I tried changing .live to .click to see if it would work and it made it worse...it's not even doing the normal redirect now.  I will search for a new tutorial though.  I would like to low if I post the rendered code from the browser would you be willing to take another look at it to see if you can find the issue?  I can have it pisted this evening.  Thanks.

Comment: It cannot possibly make it worse. And what do you mean _not even doing the normal redirect now_? You making ajax calls and the whole purpose of ajax is to stay on the same page, not redirect so its unclear what your trying to do.

Comment: Yes, it did.  When I clicked on the link to pop up the dialog, it was showing the form on a new page.  Now, when I click on the link, its not even doing that.  Please see the rendered code I added to the original post to see what scripts loaded and in what order.  Maybe you can tell what's wrong.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but I (and I doubt anyone) wont wade through all that - your original question was already a code dump, 90% of which was irrelevant to the question. Refer [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Well, thanks anyway.

Comment: To 'fix' a deprecated use of `.live()` you want to change it to use `.on()` -- changing it back to just `.click()` IS NOT what you want.

Comment: Try rendering your anchor with the class `openDialog` using straight HTML rather than `ActionLink`.  You don't want a postback on that click -- you only want for your Javascript `.on('click'` event to execute.

Comment: Thanks David, I'm giving 'em a try to see what happens.

Comment: Hey David, tried both your suggestions and it didn't work.